# Is it possible to filter the wp_footer() scripts, read the content, and insert them inline?

Tags: plugins, php, wp-query, javascript, request-filter

I need to intercept the scripts that are added in the footer and head through the `wp_footer()` and `wp_head()` functions, something like `add_filter('wp_footer', my_function)` and then in `my_function`, I would check the **name of the registered script** and then perform an action, in that case would read the contents of the `script.js` file and insert it inline, something like this:

Before intercept (this is showing on footer or head):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="mywp/wp-content/plugins/plugin-name/script.js">
```

After intercept, I want to show inline script like this:

```
<script>
    // this is content of plugin script.js or other intercepted scripts...
    var content_is_here = ....
    function() {
        // content inline etc
    ...
    }
</script>
```

Is possible do this? On intercepting, i need name of script and path to read the content and insert inline, this I know how to do, but I don't have idea of how to intercept scripts...

If is possible to intercept CSS files too would be very good!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For scripts you can use the [`script_loader_tag`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/script_loader_tag/) filter, which is run right before the script tag is output. It filters the HTML `<script>` tag, but it also passes the handle and URL that you can use to extract the contents and replace the script tag with a version that has the script inline:

```
function wpse_292955_inline_script( $script, $handle, $src ) {
    if ( $handle === 'script-handle' ) {
        $script = sprintf( '<script type="text/javascript">%s</script>', file_get_contents( $src ) );
    }

    return $script;
}
add_filter( 'script_loader_tag', 'wpse_292955_inline_script', 10, 3 );
```

There's also [`style_loader_tag`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/style_loader_tag/) for styles:

```
function wpse_292955_inline_style( $html, $handle, $href, $media ) {
    if ( $handle === 'style-handle' ) {
        $html = sprintf( 
            '<style type="text/css" media="%s">%s</style>', 
            esc_attr( $media ),
            file_get_contents( $href )
        );
    }

    return $html;
}
add_filter( 'style_loader_tag', 'wpse_292955_inline_style', 10, 4 );
```

Note that because scripts and styles are registered with a URL the URL will need to be accessible by your server for `file_get_contents()` to work, so it probably won't work in a local development environment.

Comment: You can try to derive the path from the URL though.

Comment: Thanks! I made a modification to verify that the file exists and also to load the local file: 

    if ( $handle === 'script-handle' ) {
        $url = explode(get_site_url(), $src);
        $path = strtok($url[1], '?');
        $path = str_replace('/', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $path);
        $complete_path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].$path;

        if(file_exists($complete_path)) {
            $script = sprintf( '<script type="text/javascript">%s</script>', file_get_contents( $complete_path ) );
        }
    }